# Laravel ajax URL issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm new to Laravel and using Ajax for some functionalities.

```
//Route
Route::post('some/thing/','Controller@Method');

//jQuery
$('.some_class').click(function(){
        var var1 = $('.some').val();
        var val2 = $(".another").val();
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            //this part
            url: "some/thing/",
            type:"POST",
            data: { var1: var1,val2: val2,_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
            success:function(response){
               console.log("working");
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });

//controller
public function Method(Request $object){
   if(isset($_POST['val1'])){//do something}
}
```

problem is in the URL parameter of AJAX. When I'm giving value to the url i.e some/thing/, it gives me 404 error showing **www.siteurl/some/thing/some/thing/** not found and when I'm keeping url value blank then it's working. But then i don't think it's a good practice to do like this.

I have seperate .js file in public folder.
Controller in different and blade file in different directory. Laravel version 5.6.22

thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `ajaxSetup` headers? https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Comment: Try by giving CSRF token seperately

Comment: Like this                 
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use absolute path instead of relative. append `/` before the url like `"/some/thing/"`

```
$('.some_class').click(function(){
        var var1 = $('.some').val();
        var val2 = $(".another").val();
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            //this part
            url: "/some/thing/",
            type:"POST",
            data: { var1: var1,val2: val2,_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
            success:function(response){
               console.log("working");
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If unable to use a route name, this solution works! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to change the Url to the absolute path:

Incase you are working on **Blade file**:

Change the url from :  `url: "some/thing/",`

To url: `{{url('some/thing')}},`

In case you are working on **external Js File**:

Change the url from :  `url: "some/thing/",`

To url: `url: "/some/thing/",`

Answer (score 2):

When you write the url to ajax  its trying to achieve some/thing/some/thing/ 
To fix; give a name for your route and then use this name for your ajax url.

```
//Route
Route::post('some/thing/','Controller@Method')->name('yourRouteName');

//jQuery
$('.some_class').click(function(){
        var var1 = $('.some').val();
        var val2 = $(".another").val();
        var CSRF_TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        $.ajax({
            //this part
            url: "{{ route('yourRouteName') }}",
            type:"POST",
            data: { var1: var1,val2: val2,_token: CSRF_TOKEN},
            success:function(response){
               console.log("working");
            },
            error:function(){
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: didn't work for me. May be because I'm using different .js file for ajax. it made a URL like www.siteurl/some/thing/some/thing/20%{{ route('yourRouteName') }}20%. Thank you anyways.

Comment: {{ route('yourRouteName') }}  should be in php file.  it is  php code.

Comment: and if you dont want to put your js to php file,  try this;   url: "/some/thing/"

Comment: yes sir, used the second solution and now it's working perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **route** in **$except array** in **VerifyCsrfToken** **middle ware** to ignore **csrf token verification** on that route

```
 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

    class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
    {
        /**
         * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $except = [

              "/some/thing/"

        ];
    }
```